# Standard error of linear combination of coefficients from separate regressions

Tags: regression, standard-error

Suppose I run $N$ regressions of the form predicting future data with historic data (one year lag say):
$$y_t = \beta_i*x_{t-1} $$
for $t=1\dots N$ to obtain $N$ coefficients $\hat \beta_i : i=1\dots N$. Now I am interested in the mean of these coefficients as an estimate
$$\tilde\beta = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N 
\hat\beta_i$$ 
what would be the standard error of $
\tilde\beta$ here. I am not sure how to treat linear combination of regression coefficients from separate regressions.

My best guess would be:
$$Var(\tilde\beta) = \frac{1}{N^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^NVar(\hat\beta_i) + 2\cdot\sum_{i,j}Cov(\hat\beta_i, \hat\beta_j)\right)$$
the second sum is all the covariance pairs. If this is correct, I'm not sure how to obtain the covariance terms.

Comment: Because you cannot get covariance, your approach has problem. Try to fit ONE model for all of Ys.